# start & stop Nginx , mysql server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing a **Rails v2.3** app. with **MySQL v5.1** database on a **Ubuntu** machine.

I know the commands to start, stop **Nginx** and **MySQL** on command line.

But now, I need to have the following process defined in one of my **rake task** of my Rails app.:

```
stop Nginx --> stop(shut down) MySQL --> ... --> start MySQL --> start Nginx
```

Which means all these need to be defined in ruby script in a **rake task** of my **Rails** app.

I am not sure how to make ruby code run the above process(execute the commands) in my **rake task**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Ruby's Kernel module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60) (it's built in). Using backticks, you can run the commands to stop/start nginx and MySQL, and even check their exit codes to make sure they executed properly (If your stop/start scripts support exit codes).

Example:

```
# In your Rakefile
namespace :servers do
  task :stop do
    nginx_stop_output = `service nginx stop`
    if $?.exitstatus != 0
      # handle shutdown failure
    end

    mysql_stop_output = `service mysql stop`
    if $?.exitstatus != 0
      # handle shutdown failure
    end
  end

  task :start do
    nginx_start_output = `service nginx start`
    if $?.exitstatus != 0
      # handle startup failure
    end

    mysql_start_output = `service mysql start`
    if $?.exitstatus != 0
      # handle startup failure
    end
  end
end
```

Substitute in your own stop/start commands in the backticks.

You can then run these tasks with `rake servers:stop` and `rake servers:start`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless nginx does not run on port 80, you probably use sudo. In that case your options are:

1. Modify `/etc/sudoers` to permit your user to work with nginx without being asked for a password.
2. Use `Open3#popen3` instead of `` or `system()` to run shell commands. Open3 lets you interact with the command if it prompts you for additional info, so you can type in the sudo password when your rake task tries to execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the gem [systemu](https://github.com/ahoward/systemu) to execute commands. It's better than any of the built-in Ruby command line facilities. To take care of your server environment you might look into a deployment framework like [vlad](https://github.com/seattlerb/vlad).